# Custom UIButton with local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a custom button that then schedules a local notification. The code I've found on here seems to be outdated. I've looked at the outlines from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html
But I'm still pretty confused. Can anyone post a clean and concise example including which files I put which code? (Including registering) Even just an example of creating any local notification would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by notification?  Push notification?

Comment: Well I think for my purposes I only need a local notification.

Comment: What do you mean a local notification?  Like a popover appearing in the app at a scheduled time?

Comment: According to what I've read, if a notification can just be scheduled, then its considered a local notification. If the notification needs to be remotely sent and pass through servers, its a push notification.

Comment: @DSmith Hi did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppDelegate.m, register the types of user interactions the app supports (from iOS 8.0 and later)

```
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationType) (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

Inside the button tapped method you do this:

```
NSDate * fireDate; // The schedule date time.
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotification.alertBody = @"alertText";
localNotification.alertAction = @"buttonTitle";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


// Schedule it with the app
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

In AppDelegate.m add this method to handle when a local notification arrives (if necessary):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification{
    // This method gets called when a local notification arrives
}
```